# SharePoint Limit to mentions in a post

Tags: sharepoint

How many mentions in a same post is possible to do in SharePoint 2013?

I thought there was a limit for three mentions, but while I was testing it, I was capable to mention in it more than three.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mention as many people as you like, but only 3 of them can be notified and will have link to their profile.